# Delete duplicate object(JSON) nodes - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a JSON string:

```
var jsn = '{"header-v1":{"archives":{"is_author":"all"}},"header-v4":{"archives":{"is_author":"all"}}}';
```

This object is constantly updated and I want to remove duplicate values. For example, if it is:

```
    var jsn = '{"header-v4":{"archives":{"is_author":"all"}}}';
```

And if the new rule set which should be added will be equal to

```
"header-v1":{"archives":{"is_author":"all"}}
```

then I want to remove `"header-v4":{"archives":{"is_author":"all"}}` from there, because there is a duplicate of `{"archives":{"is_author":"all"}}`.

Is that even possible with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = [];
$.each(subservices, function (i, e) {
    var matchingItems = $.grep(result, function (item) {
       return item.name === e.name && item.label === e.label;
    });
    if (matchingItems.length === 0){
        result.push(e);
    }
});

//displays result [{"name":"hello","label":"world"},{"name":"abc","label":"xyz"}]
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

JS fiddel
http://jsfiddle.net/defujjhp/

Comment: Nope, even this does not work. Please see my comment on @Manish post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this you can do

```
var jsn = '{"header-v4":{"archives":{"is_author":"all"}}}';

var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsn);

var newJsn = '{header-v1":{"archives":{"is_author":"all"}}}';

var newJsonObject = JSON.parse(newJsn);

var matchingKey = [];

Object.keys(newJsonObject).forEach(key => {
    Object.keys(jsonObject).forEach(nkey => {
        if(newJsonObject[key].toString() === jsonObject[nkey].toString()) {
          matchingKey.push(nkey);
        }
    });
});

matchingKey.forEach(mkey => {
    delete jsonObject[mkey];
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but if initial object `jsonObject` contains multiple objects, your code removes all of them. I just need to remove the duplicate of a new object from initial JSON and then insert the new object on its place.

In short, I want to replace old (duplicate) value with a new one. Here is a JSBin example: https://jsbin.com/gekagavabe/edit?js,console

Comment: Can you check if you need this https://jsbin.com/hopefenapu/edit?js,console

Comment: Thanks for the effort but it's still not that what I want. Your script removed everything and just added a new string `{"header-v1":{"archives":{"is_author":"all"}}}` to JSON.


When `{"header-v1":{"archives":{"is_author":"all"}}}` is added I want to remove only `"header-v4":{"archives":{"is_author":"all"}}}` from there, because it's a duplicate of a new value. Is it clear now?

Comment: Do you want to remove only last Object? because `"header-v3":{"archives":{"is_search":"all"}}` also duplicate of new value so i removed all the duplicate value from object

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate. `"is_search"` and `"is_author"` is not the same.

Comment: Got it. https://jsbin.com/tisatayeqa/edit?js,console this solution should work for you.